# How to Deselect 1 vertices from each end of selected edge strip of vertices?

Tags: modeling, select, loop

So, lets understand what I am trying to say here[image]
In the picture I made simple mesh and selected verts so, in the first square piece all boundary edges are selected hence its a close loop, and every other selected edge is open loop of verts. So I want to develop a code that deselects the each vertice that is on end of open loop and the closed edge/vert loop should be unchanged. Result desired:- [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to make it into a menu item or an actual addon. But if you run this script in your text editor you can search for the operator and it should work.

````
import bpy
import bmesh

class DeselectOuterVerts(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Deselect the outermost vertices on a non-cyclic edge loop selection."""
    bl_idname = "mesh.deselect_outer_verts"
    bl_label = "Deselect Outer Verts"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    # method to identify verts that are on the outside of 
    # the edgeloop selection
    @staticmethod
    def is_inner_vert(vert, sel_edges):
        num = 0
        for e in vert.link_edges:
            if e in sel_edges:
                num += 1
        # if the number of edges connected to the vertex
        # that is also in the current edge selection is < 2
        # then we know that this vertex is on the outside
        return num == 2
    
    @staticmethod
    def both_verts_in_selection(edge, vert_selection):
        v1, v2 = edge.verts[:]
        return bool((v1 in vert_selection) * (v2 in vert_selection))

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
        sel_edges = [e for e in bm.edges[:] if e.select]
        sel_verts = [v for v in bm.verts[:] if v.select]

        num_verts = len(set(sel_verts))
        num_edges = len(sel_edges)
        
        # if only two verts are selected then do nothing
        if num_verts == 2:
            return {"FINISHED"}
        
        if num_verts > num_edges:
            for v in sel_verts:
                if not self.is_inner_vert(v, sel_edges):
                    v.select_set(False)
                    bm.select_history.discard(v)
            
            # it seems like just setting one of the two vertices of an edge to 
            # unselected is not enough to also set the edge to be deselected
            
            new_sel_verts = [v for v in bm.verts[:] if v.select]
            
            # this is probably a stupid way to solve this problem but eff it.
            # it works.
            
            # loops back through the edges, find if both verts are selected, 
            # if not then set that edge to be deselected.
            
            for e in sel_edges:
                if not self.both_verts_in_selection(e, new_sel_verts):
                    e.select_set(False)
                    bm.select_history.discard(e)
                    
            # this action deselects the edge entirely, which means it 
            # deselects one too many verts, so we need to go back and 
            # set the selected vertices to at least the original selection. 
            
            for v in new_sel_verts:
                v.select_set(True)
                
            # now this operator has the benefit of working properly 
            # on both edge and vertex selections
            
            
                   
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DeselectOuterVerts)
  

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DeselectOuterVerts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

  

```
````

Comment: Yeah It's great and working I implement a button to test and it worked but, Lets say I pressed the button once and it deselects the outer verts. But if I again press the button it does nothing, Do you know why? Like technically If I press button again and again it should go on and deselect end verts from the updated mesh too, but it doesn't. Also it also deselects the loop which have only 2 verts,

Comment: I edited the code, it should work as expected now.